# ruby on rails: empty database records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am building a basic application for learning purpose.

I build a form and when I use the Save button, a record is created but it is a empty record with only an Id.

I hope someone can help me.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
      resources :relaties   
  root 'welcome#index'
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>Nieuwe Relatie</h1>

<%= form_for :relatie, url: "/relaties"  do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :naam %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :naam %>
  </p>

 <p>
    <%= f.label :straatnaam %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :straatnaam %>
  </p>

 <p>
    <%= f.label :huisnummer %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :huisnunmmer %>
  </p>

 <p>
    <%= f.label :postcode %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :postcode %>
  </p>

 <p>
    <%= f.label :plaats %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :plaats %>
  </p>

 <p>
    <%= f.label :omschrijving %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :omschrijving %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**relaties_controller.rb**

```
class RelatiesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @relatie = Relatie.new
    end

    def create
        @relatie = Relatie.new(params[:relatie])    

        @relatie.save
        redirect_to(@relatie)
    end

    private
  def relatie_params
    params.require(:relatie).permit(:naam, :straatnaam, :huisnummer, :postcode, :plaats, :omschrijving) 
  end   

    def show
        @relatie = Relatie.find(params[:id])
    end 
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating/ updating a record you should whitelist the attributes that you would like to be saved in database. You have added a method named `relatie_params` to do that BUT you have not used it in the code which is why when you try to create a new `Relatie` record none of the attributes are stored in database as they are not white-listed.

In `create` action, replace

```
 @relatie = Relatie.new(params[:relatie])
```

with

```
 @relatie = Relatie.new(relatie_params)
```

For your reference, read about [Strong Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) which was introduced in `Rails 4`